# Are any Japanese words ever intentionally misspelled for any reason?

Tags: word-choice, slang

I came across the words "Boyz", and "EZ" in English, and wondered if any Kanji characters were used in the same way. Thank you very much.

Comment: I know it happens a lot in casual speech, and so it might happen when you use hiragana or katakana, but I don't think it would happen with kanji

Comment: What about puns (especially those based on homophones) or Kanji that get assigned a different reading (like 少年 with ボーイズ as furigana)?

Comment: You [already know such examples](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44128/5010), but you mean you want kanji examples?

Comment: @naruto Yes please.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<sup>(It's easier to give examples using kana (それで**わ**, もうやめ**れ**, 止め**ろ**ください, **ぬ**こ, イ**ソ**ターネット, メー**ノレ**, ふ**いん**き, ようつべ, ...), but you want examples with kanji? Okay...)</sup>

{{pad}} For historical reasons Japanese kanij compounds can have dozens of [同音異字語](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15924/5010) (homophones; words that share the same reading but have different kanji). And some argot and net-slang words are based on this fact. Perhaps the best-known example is 厨房, which is from a misspelling(?) of 中坊 (cf. [Use of 厨 on the Internet](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/239/5010)). Similar examples are writing 脂肪【しぼう】 ("fat") instead of 死亡【しぼう】 ("death"), writing 妊娠【にんしん】 ("pregnant") instead of 任信【にんしん】 ("Nintendo fanboy").

{{pad}} Many slang words were made by creating funny *ateji* for existing words (including loanwords). 夜露死苦 meaning よろしく is a typical example (cf. [Origin of 夜露死苦?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15138/5010)) Other famous examples are 鯖【さば】 meaning *server*, プロ串【くし】 (or just 串) meaning *proxy*, 垢【あか】 meaning *account*, 尼【あま】 meaning *Amazon.co.jp*, 裏山【うらやま】 meaning うらやましい ("I envy it").

Most of the words I wrote here are more or less dirty or at least heavily slangy, so please don't try to use them. I won't.