# Meaning of 電凸 in suicide context

Tags: meaning, words, slang, internet-slang

Context: in a manga, a video of a person filming himself with a smartphone while committing suicide jumping in front of a train has the following title:

> 早朝にガチの電凸してみた

As far as I understood from the [Wikipedia article for 電凸](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%BB%E5%87%B8), they are complaint phone calls or emails towards companies, mass media, government, etc. Why was the word used in the context I explained above? Does it have any relation to suicide? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it's a kind of pun, or rather, [釣り](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_tsuri.htm)タイトル.

The slang word 電凸 usually means 電話で突撃 as the Wikipedia article says, but in this video, this title actually means something like 電車に突入. (凸 is a [slangy kanji replacement](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44255/5010) of 突 used among some net users.) ガチの means "real", "serious". Everyone will understand what 電凸 actually means in this video only after clicking the title and see him jumping in front of a train.

(Or maybe this was intended to be a camouflage; a title like 自殺してみた would have been immediately blocked, but 電凸してみた would look like just another joke video.)

Comment: Am I the only one who assumed 凸 doubles as a visualization of a head or some other bodily mass lying on top of (or protruding from) a rail right in front of the incoming 電?

Comment: @Will Yes, I suppose that's why 凸 was chosen among other kanji that can be read as トツ.