# Help with meaning of 新規掲載絵皆無貧困絵描

Tags: word-choice, words

An artist I follow on twitter posted an image and above it they wrote 新規掲載絵皆無貧困絵描. (Here is the link to the original tweet: https://twitter.com/sai_no/status/1033339861351256065 tho it doesn't really have much contextual information for me to use)

I know all of the individual kanji that is contained in that phrase, but I fail to see how they all fit together. Google translator and other translation tools just translate individual components that make it up, and I don't understand how they connect.

It would help me if someone could explain to me in a more nuanced way what that phrase means and break down how it's components work together to make it.

Comment: This is an example of [偽中国語](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57115/5010).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably trying to say "a poor painter with no new pictures published".

新規掲載の絵が皆無な、貧困に陥{おちい}った絵描き: a painter in poverty who doesn't have any newly published pictures