# What does "推し鯖" mean?

Tags: translation

I was browsing stuff related to the game Fate Grand Order when I ran into the word "推し鯖". There's an entire hashtag for it on twitter.
https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E6%8E%A8%E3%81%97%E9%AF%96

I've learned that 鯖 is slang for server. But what does 推し mean in this instance? Dictionary says its "fan" or "supporter" of. Does this mean like an unofficial "fan server"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

推し鯖 means "(my) favorite servant(s)". 鯖【さば】 is usually slang for server (it's "[ateji argot](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44255/5010)"), but in FGO it stands for [servant](https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/wiki/Servant_List_by_ID). Here, 推し is another recent slang word which means "favorite (idol/character)". 推し on its own doesn't mean "supporter", but X推し can mean "fan/supporter/follower of X". 推し originally means "recommending" or "pushing", and this meaning was coined and popularized among [AKB48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKB48) fans 10 years ago or so.

Comment: Only Japanese could muster the bizarre sense development ‘push mackerel’ > ‘favourite servant’!